# know when @Input parameter is changed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to exec a function every time when the @Input is changed.
I tried to do it that way:

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange }) {
  if( changes['inputName'] && changes['inputName'].previousValue != changes['inputName'].currentValue ) {
    this.func();
  }
}
```

but my problem is:
my @Input value is'nt necessarily changed
(it can be "a" and another once "a")
but even if it's not changed I want to exec the function.
what can I do?

Comment: maybe you just get rid of this if statement and just fire this.func() in ngOnChanges body?

Comment: it can be a good idea, but i have some inputs, and I want to exec the function only when the specific input is changed.

Comment: What is the type of your input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call setter method For @Input() changed everytime..

```
@Input('inputName') set cmpRef (cmp : any){
   // your function call here goes every time @Input() changes, this setter method is called.
      this.func();
 }
```

Comment: I tried to do that but the set works only in the first time when the input is changed and not every time.

Comment: You have to Immutable your object for Input() to work properly, For this you can use destructing or Object.assign()

Comment: @Tammar If answer is helpul to you, You can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by putting object in the @Input parameter instead of string only.
and now it is changed every time I change it.